# UIInterfaceOrientation problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

My program is not supporting the UIInterfaceOrientation. Program will not support the UIInterfaceOrientation after I add the UITabBarItem.Please give a solution. Also I added the navigationController.
Here is my code.

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
//I create my navigation Controller
    //UINavigationController *navigationController;
    //I create my TabBar controlelr
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    // Icreate the array that will contain all the View controlelr
    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
    // I create the view controller attached to the first item in the TabBar

sivajitvViewController *firstViewController;
firstViewController = [[sivajitvViewController alloc]init];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
//[navigationController.tabBarItem initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:1];
firstViewController.navigationItem.title=@"Gallery";
//viewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"natural.jpg"];
navigationController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery.png"];
navigationController.tabBarItem.title = @"Gallery";
//navigationController.headerTitle = @"Some Title";


[localControllersArray addObject:navigationController];
[navigationController release];
[firstViewController release];

// I create the view controller attached to the second item in the TabBar

SecondViewController *secondViewController;
secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
//[navigationController.tabBarItem initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:2];
navigationController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"News.png"];
navigationController.tabBarItem.title = @"News";


[localControllersArray addObject:navigationController];
[navigationController release];
[secondViewController release];

// load up our tab bar controller with the view controllers
tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;

// release the array because the tab bar controller now has it
[localControllersArray release];

// add the tabBarController as a subview in the window
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

// need this last line to display the window (and tab bar controller)
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Which UIInterfaceOrientation does your app not support?

Comment: Question not clear. Please give more specific details.

Answer (score 2):

If you have UITabBarController, **all** the tabs should support your interface orientation. So if you have 3 tabs and 2 of them support portrait and landscape, but the last one supports only portrait, you application will **never** turn to landscape.